# What to do when scientific notation exceeds the toPrecision range

Tags: javascript, scientific-notation

I would like to show some numbers on a website which are now in scientific notation. I am using toPrecision to show normal notation for the numbers.

Unfortunately toPrecision only works in the range from 1e-6 to 1e20 and I do have numbers like 1e-7 and 1e-10.

So what can I do when toPrecision doesn't do the job I would like it to do?

I tried using Number() and parseFloat() and even both to try to get this number to be shown in normal notation...

```
var min =  1e7,
nr1 = parseFloat(Number(min).toPrecision()),
nr2 = Number(min).toPrecision(),
nr3 = min.toPrecision(),
nr4 = min.toString();

console.log(nr1); //1e-7
console.log(nr2); //1e-7
console.log(nr3); //1e-7
console.log(nr4); //1e-7
```

Nothing worked so far.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [`toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)?

Comment: toExponential will turn a normal notation into scientific. the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried `var min = 1e42; min.toLocaleString();`? This converts scientific notation to decimal notation.

Comment: I tried using toLocaleString();  didn't work. I created a small function to fix the issue using toFixed which is able to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't find a real solution. I know toFixed() does work, however you need to give the total digits you want to receive back.

Per example:

```
 var nr = 1e-7;     
 console.log(nr.toFixed(10)) //=> 0.0000001000
```

that's not really nice to see as well. So this script does work.
However Javascript can mess it up again. Per example I was using D3 to create a graph and although the number is going in there with normal notation, it will come out again in scientific... 
So it is very fragile...

```
function newToFixed(nr) {
    arr1 = (""+nr).split("e"),
    arr2 = [],
    fixedPos = null;

    //notation is already normalized
    if (arr1.length === 1) {        
        return nr;
    }

    /**
     * remove the + or - from the number 
     * now have the exact number digits we want to use in toFixed
     */
    if (arr1[1].indexOf("+") === 0) {
        arr2 = arr1[1].split("+");
    } else {
        arr2 = arr1[1].split("-");
    }

    //making sure it is a number and not a string
    fixedPos = Number(arr2[1]); 
    return nr.toFixed(fixedPos); //returns  0.0000001
}
```